# Jenssegers mongodb Auth::user() - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: mongodb, laravel, authentication, jenssegers-mongodb

Reading Jenssegers mongodb documentation i have install this module to get access to mongodb functions. In first step I configure user login/registration issues and after catch this error.

`Trying to get property of non-object ... array('guard' => null)

I need to get current user Id in custom controller:

`use Auth;`

`//method`

`...`

`Auth::guard('site')->user();`

`...`

`//`

But I get `NULL` from `Auth::user()`. All data is set in Auth (`[Auth][SessionGuard][User]`) and exist, but here i see issue about `_id` field in `[user]` object from table. So native user() method want find `id` field in object. How can I change old `id` to `_id` to get `user()`? Anybody had this issue before?

Comment: Whether your User model class extends Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model?

Answer (score 0):

verify your user model:

```
*//
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable{
/* */
}*
```

If you are using api routes, try change your middleware  in app\http\routeServiceProvider.php in mapApiRoutes() function

```
->middleware('api')
```

to:

```
->middleware('web')
```